# entity framework model for oracle

Tags: asp.net

I want to use entity framework model for visual studio 2010. I am using oracle database. i was wondering
if it is possible to use entity framework for oracle. If it is not possible then I will just use simple ADO.net and call stord proc and packages.

I already downloaded oracle data provider for entity frameowrk from codeplex web site. I could not see oracle database option when connecting to oracle databse in LINQ to sql.

can someone give me any example that connects to a sample oracle database and use LINQ to oracle

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes use the Oracle provider: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider check out the instructions provided and see if these instructions help you get up and running.